# Excel Opens CSV Files and Truncates Decimals to Significant Digits

Tags: excel, csv

I am opening a CSV files that looks like this,

`24.0000,19.2500,4.0000,0.7500,`

and Excel displays the following truncated values with just the significant digits.

`24  |  19.25  |  4  |  0.75`

But I need to keep the 4 decimal places (even if insignificant). Is it possible to somehow keep my CSV as auto-Text, not Number, to be displayed in Excel? Even when I tried quotes around the values, `"4.0000`, it still truncated.

I tried these options in the CSV to make it read as Text:

`4.000[space]`

`"4.000   "`

None of these worked. The only one that worked was with a non-digit,
`4.000a`

So Excel recognizes all-digit fields as Numbers, and forces truncation unless it sees a non-digit?

Comment: Use the import wizard and then you can force the column to be text in the setup.  There is no way if you just open the file in excel.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Sub test()
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim Path As String, Fn As String
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim txtFree As Long
    Dim vS As Variant, v As Variant
    Dim vDB(1 To 1000, 1 To 100) As String
    Dim r As Long, c As Integer

    Path = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    Filename = "csvtest.csv" '<~~ your csv filename
    Fn = Path & Filename

    txtFree = FreeFile()
    Open Fn For Input As #txtFree
    Do While Not EOF(txtFree)
        Line Input #txtFree, Fn
        vS = Split(Fn, ",")
        r = r + 1
        c = 0
        For Each v In vS
            c = c + 1
            vDB(r, c) = v
        Next v

    Loop
    Range("a1").Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB
End Sub
```

result image

[image]

Comment: @gene b, Dim vDB(1 To 1000, 1 To 100) : set  the row size, column size  base on your data.